# Why does Visual Studio 2015 keep removing file from Project?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using VS2015 for a particular project, and once or twice a week, I'm hitting Ctrl-S to save an edited file and must be hitting something else by mistake and find that the file I had open is not only closed, but removed from the project.
The file does still exist on the hard drive and can be added back into the project once I realise it's been removed.

I have looked through all the shortcuts and can't for the life of me figure out what's happening.

I never see this issue in VS2019, so I'm wondering if it's actually a bug in VS2015??

If anyone knows what the heck is going on, please let me know.

Comment: Check if you have a conflicting keyboard shortcut on your configuration.

Comment: Can't see anything. I'm fairly sure VS2015 is broken, as now if I try and move a window while an app is running, VS crashes and restarts.

Comment: Could you try resetting all settings to their default?

Comment: I daren't reset anything - it's now got the to the state where if I even move a window while debugging, VS crashes and restarts.

Sorry for the late reply - I've spent the last couple of weeks re-writing the project from scratch in VS2019 then porting the code, so I can say goodbye to VS2015 for good.